# IS there a possibility to loop through dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
dflist = [DP, SMP, SMD, MP, MD, MSM, SAP, SAD,SAMA, SAM, AP,AD, ASM, AM,ASA]

for i, df in enumerate(dflist):
    # open an existing document
    doc = docx.Document()

    # add a table to the end and create a reference variable
    # extra row is so we can add the header row
    t = doc.add_table(dflist[i].shape[0]+1, dflist[i].shape[1])

    # add the header rows.
    for j in range(dflist[i].shape[-1]):
        t.cell(0,j).text = dflist[i].columns[j]

    # add the rest of the data frame
    for i in range(dflist[i].shape[0]):
        for j in range(dflist[i].shape[-1]):
            t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(dflist[i].values[i,j])

    # save the doc
    doc.save(fr'./test1[i].docx')
```

I am trying to iterate through the list of dataframes so that I create a word document for each of them.

However, I am getting the following error;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-d61049a379a0> in <module>
     14     for i in range(dflist[i].shape[0]):
     15         for j in range(dflist[i].shape[-1]):
---> 16             t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(dflist[i].values[i,j])
     17 
     18     # save the doc

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you use `i` as both the looping variable in your outer loop over the list and then inside that loop when you '#add the rest of the dataframe'. That's probably causing the wrong reference somewhere

Comment: Thank you @ALollz ! How would you write the code differently?